# regex string between two strings

Tags: regex

How can I get the text between two constant text?

Example:

```
<rate curr="KRW" unit="100">19,94</rate>
```

**19,94**

is between

```
"<rate curr="KRW" unit="100">"
```

and

```
"</rate>"
```

---

Other example:

```
ABCDEF
```

getting substring between
`AB` and `EF`= `CD`

Comment: [he com̡e̶s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Try with:

```
/<rate[^>]*>(.*?)<\/rate>/
```

However it is better **NOT TO USE REGEX WITH HTML**.

Comment: I'm expecting something like /<rate curr="KRW" unit="100">(.*?)</rate> not the general form, despite of it may works

Answer (score 2):

The way I do it is using the match all

```
matched = Regex.Matches(result, @"(?<=<rate curr=\"KRW\" unit=\"100\">)(.*?)(?=</rate>)");
```

Then get one by one using `match[i].Groups[1].value`

Answer (score 1):

If you're analyzing HTML, you're probably better off going with javascript and .innerHTML(). Regex is a bit overkill.

Comment: +1 and I would express the same sentiment with PHP and [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a generic solution, i.e to find a string between two strings You may use `Pattern.quote()` [or wrap string with `\Q` and `\E` around] to quote start and end strings and use `(.*?)` for a non greedy match.

See an example of its use in below snippet

```
@Test
public void quoteText(){
    String str1 = "<rate curr=\"KRW\" unit=\"100\">";
    String str2 = "</rate>";

    String input = "<rate curr=\"KRW\" unit=\"100\">19,94</rate>"
                      +"<rate curr=\"KRW\" unit=\"100\"></rate>"
                      +"<rate curr=\"KRW\" unit=\"100\">19,96</rate>";

    String regex = Pattern.quote(str1)+"(.*?)"+Pattern.quote(str2);
    System.out.println("regex:"+regex);

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while(m.find()){
        String group = m.group(1);
        System.out.println("--"+group);
    }
```

**Output**

```
regex:\Q<rate curr="KRW" unit="100">\E(.*?)\Q</rate>\E
--19,94
--
--19,96
```

*Note:Though its not recommended to use regex to parse entire HTML, I think there is no harm in conscious use of regex while treating HTML as plain text*

Answer (score 0):

The simple regex matching string you're looking for is:

```
(?<=<rate curr=\"KRW\" unit=\"100\">)(.*?)(?=</rate>)
```

In Ruby, for example, this would translate to:

```
string = '<rate curr="KRW" unit="100">19,94</rate>'

string.match("(?<=<rate curr=\"KRW\" unit=\"100\">)(.*?)(?=</rate>)").to_s
# => "19,94"
```

*Thanks to Will Yu.*

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you use an HTML parser. The grammar that defines HTML is a context-free grammar, which is fundamentally too complex to be parsed by regular expressions. Even if you manage to write a regular expression that will achieve what you want, but will probably fail on some corner cases.

For instance, what if you are expected to parse the following HTML?

```
<rate curr="KRW" unit="100"><rate curr="KRW" unit="100">19,94</rate></rate>
```

A regular expression may not handle this corner case properly.

Comment: It will never look like that **in this case**, and if it would, I dont care. I just want to know how to use regexp to find the text between two texts.